# Is there a way to make an app not know that its run in a RDP session?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, citrix, passthrough

So I'm currently having the issue that Citrix Workspace App doesn't passthrough the USB-Smartcard Reader when connected via RDP to the computer, whereas when I connect via VNC this works.
I'm basically going via VNC into a Windows VM and from there via Citrix into the Terminal Server. The Smartcard is connected to the vmware esxi host and fed to the VM and in this scenario it also gets passed through to the Terminal Server Session. However this doesn't work when connected via RDP to the Windows VM.

I'm aware that Citrix writes in it's documentation that Passthrough doesn't work when initially connected via RDP, but is there a way to make Citrix Workspace not be aware that one is connected via RDP?

Comment: VNC that can do USB? Interesting. What exact VNC client and server are you using?

Comment: No I don't mean USB over VNC. USB device is directly connected to hypervisor and gets passed through to VM. VNC is just being used to connect to the VM instead of RDP